# Create Custom module

Tags: magento-1.9, module, extensions

Hi i created custom module with this structure :

[image]

Config file code in `etc/config.xml`

```
<config>
    <modules>
        <Shareino_Sync>
            <version>0.1.0</version>
        </Shareino_Sync>
    </modules>
    <frontend>
        <routers>
            <sync>
                <use>standard</use>
                <args>
                    <module>Shareino_Sync</module>
                    <frontName>sync</frontName>
                </args>
            </sync>
        </routers>
    </frontend>

</config>
```

`app/etc/modules/Shareino_Sync.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
    <modules>
        <Shareino_Sync>
            <active>true</active>
            <codePool>local</codePool>
        </Shareino_Sync>
    </modules>
</config>
```

And i just created controller like this :
`app/code/community/Shareino/Sync/controllers/IndexController`

```
class Shareino_Sync_IndexController extends Mage_Core_Controller_Front_Action
{
    public function indexAction(){
        echo "index Action";
    }
    public function testAction(){
        echo "index Action";
    }

}
```

Always I try to open index action i got 404 error.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The simple thing your issue at codePool.

You declare **Shareino_Sync** module's codePool is local  at `Shareino_Sync.xml` .

But as per as, your code your module it located at  community codePool (`app/code/community`).

*So  you should change*

```
  <codePool>local</codePool>
```

**To**

```
  <codePool>community</codePool>
```

Comment: Better would be to move the code to the local pool probably

Comment: that is not good idea bcoz it is a 3rd party module

Comment: Huh? The OP created this module...

Comment: I would also place in Community. 
If your code is in `app/code/community` then you should define `<codePool>community</codePool>` or if it is in `app/code/local` then `<codePool>local</codePool>`. This would make OP more clearer.

Answer (score 1):

You entered wrong `codepool` :
      community

Answer (score 0):

The URL you can test with this module are the following:

- /sync which will call the `indexAction()` method
- /sync/index/test which will call the `testAction()` method

If you want to be able to access /sync/index/action you need to create an `actionAction()` method